# What are the important difference between GOTO and EXSR in RPGLE (As400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

What are the important differences between GOTO and EXSR in RPGLE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these operation codes cause the execution of code to jump to a different point within a procedure, but they have some differences.  `GOTO` is the simpler of the two, being an unconditional jump command, essentially "go to here and start executing whatever is there". This is one of the oldest commands in programming languages and its use is usually frowned upon today.  One of the goals of the "structured programming" philosophy of the 1970's was to replace `GOTO`s with conceptually higher constructs that better describe what the programmer's intent is and that make it easier to understand that intent by reading it. You can find those replacement operation codes listed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/strupro.htm).

`EXSR` is the command to execute a subroutine. While RPG does not list it among the Structured Programming Operations, it is intended to work toward the same goals of increasing code clarity, reducing errors, and minimizing code duplication. It is like a `GOTO` in that you unconditionally jump to a new section of code, but that section of code is a named subroutine within your procedure or program.  This is useful whether you just want to name sections of code more clearly, if you want a section to execute multiple times, be called from multiple places, or whether you want to take advantage of the related operation code `LEAVESR`, which acts as an easy way to get out of a subroutine before you reach the `ENDSR` and return to the section of code you were executing just after your `EXSR`.  `GOTO` can also do this, by using two labels, marked with the `TAG` operation, but it is usually less clear and you have to maintain a list of labels to keep straight how you are jumping around.

It is worth noting that *anything* that the structured operation codes can do could instead be done by `GOTO`, but that does not make it a good idea to write code that way. The higher commands were invented for the ease of people, not for the ease of the computer.  In principle, they should compile down to very similar machine code, but there is a vast difference in documenting the programmer's thought process and intent.

It is also worth noting that RPG has two different levels of subroutines, whereas most programming languages only have one. A **subroutine** exists within a procedure or program and is more similar to a `GOTO` or structured programming operation. It does not have arguments that can be passed to it or variables that are scoped to it.

A **procedure** is more like functions and subroutines that you would find in other programming languages. It can have locally scoped variables (useful so you don't have to remember to manually clear them), it can be passed arguments (useful so you don't have to have as many temporary variables declared in your main program), and it can return a value (a variable or a data structure) so that you can pass a value back to your main program. These all make procedures a more flexible option and promote better code reuse, but I have found a few drawbacks to debugging them. The RPG debug tools like the `DUMP` operation will only correctly show the values of variables if the dump is called within the procedure.  This does not work well with coding styles that have all errors be collected by one program-wide `*PSSR` subroutine. You would have to make more use of the `MONITOR` operation or put a `*PSSR` with a `DUMP` in each procedure. Also while RPG passes an error up the call stack to the calling procedure similar to many programming languages, the basic RPG language does not provide a built-in facility for your code to throw an error which is often useful for procedures to communicate failure effectively. I use a `ThrowError` procedure that I learned from the [IBM Red Paper on RPG Exception and Error Handling](http://www.astradyne.net/manuals/ip006000.pdf). These techniques can make for robust code if you apply them correctly, but it does make procedures somewhat harder to code than subroutines, especially for beginners or for simple programs. I would recommend mastering subroutines and other structured programming constructs first, then moving on to procedures.

Comment: Loved it, thank you for such a detailed explanation

Comment: This is a great answer, but at the end you say something that could cause confusion. "Also the basic RPG language does not provide a built-in facility for throwing an error up the call stack from one procedure to the calling procedure." The reality is that errors are automatically bubbled up to the next procedure. You don't have to do anything for that to happen. Just put your monitor where it makes most sense. If you  want to signal an error in RPG, you have to call a system API to send an escape message. That is indeed an issue, but many RPG shops have routines to do that when necessary.

Comment: As for the *PSSR, that is a relic of a bygone age, and does not work well in an RPG4 setting. The appropriate replacement is MONITOR ... ENDMON;

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Corrected wording per your feedback.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments to his answer, @Mike has a very good answer, but let me provide a dissenting conclusion. Most folks learning RPG these days already know how to program using structures very similar to ILE procedures. RPG's subroutines and GOTO are relics of a bygone age. Do not attempt to use either. They rely solely on global variables for communication with the rest of the program. This practice reduces code reusability, and arguably readability since any routine anywhere in the program could cause a failure in any given subroutine. Magic subroutines like *INZSR and *PSSR which are called at the whim of the compiler, yes, I know when they are called, but I don't get to call them explicitly, make error handling enigmatic at best.

Best practice is to code modern RPG using `**free`, dispense with the cycle, and use only sub-procedures for code reuse. The magic subroutines don't even work in this environment since the cycle is not compiled in. Sub-procedures can do everything a subroutine can do and more. They provide local variables, static variables, and if necessary can use global variables. They have parameters and return values. They make the programs more modular by doing away with the need for global variables, and that also makes them more readable as they no longer need be affected by code in other parts of the program.

So no, do not use either EXSR or GOTO if you can at all help it. Prefer CALLP instead, your programs will work more like you are used to, and you won't have to worry about old obsolete op codes unless you encounter them in an existing program.

Comment: I respect your opinion, and if you are not chained to an old codebase, this can promote a more modular design, but you are not correct when you say that `*PSSR` and `*INZSR` only work in the context of a cycle program. For `*INZSR`, yes that is true, but both `*PSSR` and `*INFSR` will work inside a procedure, including a no-cycle main procedure.  They will be local to each procedure and in the case of `*INFSR`, must be assigned to a procedure-local file spec, not a program-global one. They can still provide a "final catch-all" to log unexpected errors and exit gracefully instead of crashing.

Comment: I guess I wonder: does anybody get to program RPG with purely new code? Doesn't the age of the platform guarantee that everyone has legacy stuff and you have to learn these things, even if you don't use them yourself? I learned to write cycle code and output specs just because I felt I had to understand existing reports and would not learn it well if I didn't learn to write it. Same with old display file programs with indicators and subroutines.

Comment: Yes, I do that every day. And even though *INFSR, and *PSSR do work inside a procedure, they are still relics, and the modern replacement is `MONITOR`. And even if you have an old code base, new programs and procedures can be written to take advantage of new concepts. The more you modify that old codebase, the more modern it can become.